# ListView.builder inside SliverList SliverChildBuilderDelegate not rendering Images on first load

Tags: flutter, dart

my images (from api) don't render at first load unless I scroll down and back to top again

here is my code structure

```
CustomScrollView(
 slivers: [
     SliverList(
       delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(_, index) {
        return Column(children: 
                     [
                     // SLIVERBUILDER INDEX
                     Text(somedata[_index]),
                     // MY IMAGE BUILDER
                     Container(child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (_, int index){
                                        return Image.network(arrayOfImages[index]);
                                      }))
                     ]
               );
     }),
 ]
)
```

Comment: what is the  state management you using?

Comment: Hi there, I'm using GetX. but it has nothing to do with State management since the data is rendering properly. However, on the first load the images don't appear unless I scroll down and back to top again.

Answer (score -2):

Try these:

1. Wrap a column with a container or any parent that could give its child constraints.

> ```
> SliverList(
>             delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
>               (context, index) {
>                 return Container(   // warp with container
>                   height: 450,
>                   child: Column(children: [
>                     // SLIVERBUILDER INDEX
>                     Text('title'),
> ```

2. Wrap ListView.builder with Expanded and add itemCount Property. (In your case 'arrayOfImage.length')

> ```
>  // MY IMAGE BUILDER
>                         Expanded(                 // add this widget
>                           child: ListView.builder(
>                             itemCount: arrayOfImage.length,  // add this line
> ```